# Get Value from table when page break

Tags: reporting-services

I put a table and a textbox in the body area.
There are three columns in the talble, ItemType, ItemId, ItemName
Page breaks when ItemType changed.

The expression of the textbox is "=First(Fields!ItemType.Value, "DataSet1")".
Set RepeatWith property to "Talix1".

When Report runs, in the 1st page, the value of the textbox is "Green" .
but 2nd page the value is still "Green". In fact I want to see "Red"

What should I do to change the value when page breaks?

thank you for your help.

[Report Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPQrw.png) [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQo6o.png)

Comment: The textbox must be in the body area. It's easy to implement in header or footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the text-box is currently outside of any data-set context, the value will not change. The expression is grabbing the first value in the data-set each time. Changing the page will not change the first value in the data-set.

You are going to have to put your text-box, and table, inside a List. Once that is done, set the group properties of the List to group, and page break, based on item type (`ItemType`). You can set these from the context menu you get when you right-click the Details for the List in the Row Groups pane, and choose Group Properties.

You can remove the grouping from the table since the List will handle that now.

By doing this, you now have your text-box in a data-set context. The expression for the value of the text-box can be changed to something like the following.

`=First(Fields!ItemType.Value)`

The scope is no longer needed since that too is set by the List.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: @SuikaLea Excellent! If you would be so kind as to mark the answer as accepted, I would appreciate that. And, welcome to SO!!